# How can I analyze [no source] chunk of source-map-explorer generated source map?

Tags: angular, dictionary, bundle, explorer

I have an Angular 12 application, and the bundle size seem to be pretty big, which is not expected (there is only a few component in the application). I tried to analyze the bundle with source-map-explorer, but on the generated source map there is a [no source] chunk which takes up 53% of my bundle. Another thing that I noticed that I only see the node_modules chunk, there is no available source for my "own code".

What seems to be the problem here and how can I analyze that 1.7 Mb part of my application bundle?

[See my source map here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHYUB.png)

Comment: might be best to setup a minimal stackblitz of your Angular 12 app that will help to see how you have the app setup.

Answer (score 1):

From [source-map-explorer](https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer#what-might-contribute-to-a-generated-file-size) itself:

> Mapped code without source. It might be code generated by a bundler (e.g. webpack). Represented by [no source] in explore result.

Since it represents mapped code without source there is no source that can be analyzed. That's my understanding anyway.